siesta: current-voltage threshold value is not consistent with the band gap value
I am simulating the current-voltage characteristic of armchair graphene nanoribbons.
Here is my device:

First, I got the band structure of armchair graphene nanoribbons electrode in its supercell.

Then I got current-voltage characteristic for a bias voltage from 0 to 1.3V using interpolating the hamiltonian to calculate for all the required biases.

As far as I know, the current-voltage threshold value should be consistent with the band gap value, in my case, the band gap is around 0.1247 eV, then, the threshold voltage should be around 0.1247V. However, the current is almost zero until 0.8 V.
I am using siesta-5.0.0 and my input parameters for transiesta and Tbtrans are generated by bash-script tselecs.sh from the tutorial https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial.
I would like to ask which parameters should be played with to check the influences.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
In case needed, this is the input file.
SolutionMethod transiesta

%block kgrid.MonkhorstPack
    1  0  0 0.
    0  3  0 0.
    0  0  1 0.
%endblock kgrid.MonkhorstPack

TS.Voltage 0 eV
%block TS.ChemPots
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.ChemPots

%block TS.ChemPot.Left
  mu V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      C-Left
      T-Left
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Left
%block TS.ChemPot.Right
  mu -V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      C-Right
      T-Right
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Right

TS.Contours.Eq.Pole 2.5 eV
%block TS.Contour.C-Left
  part circle
   from -40. eV + V/2 to -10 kT + V/2
     points 25
      method g-legendre
       opt right
%endblock TS.Contour.C-Left
%block TS.Contour.T-Left
  part tail
   from prev to inf
     points 10
      method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.T-Left
%block TS.Contour.C-Right
  part circle
   from -40. eV -V/2 to -10 kT -V/2
     points 25
      method g-legendre
       opt right
%endblock TS.Contour.C-Right
%block TS.Contour.T-Right
  part tail
   from prev to inf
     points 10
      method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.T-Right

MSG: You may need to correct the TS.Contours.nEq for signs of bias
MSG: The energies must be in increasing order (you may use |V|/2 to designate absolute values)
%block TS.Contours.nEq
  neq-1
%endblock TS.Contours.nEq
%block TS.Contour.nEq.neq-1
  part line
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq-1
%block TS.Contour.nEq.neq-2
  part line
   from prev to 
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq-2
%block TS.Contour.nEq.neq-1
  part line
   from prev to |V|/2 + 5 kT
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq-1
%block TS.Elecs
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.Elecs

%block TS.Elec.Left
  HS ../ELEC.TSHS
  chemical-potential Left
  semi-inf-direction -a2
  electrode-position 1
%endblock TS.Elec.Left
%block TS.Elec.Right
  HS ../ELEC.TSHS
  chemical-potential Right
  semi-inf-direction +a2
  electrode-position end -1
%endblock TS.Elec.Right
%block TBT.HS.Files
   ../0.0/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.0 eV
   ../0.1/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.1 eV
   ../0.2/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.2 eV
   ../0.3/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.3 eV
   ../0.4/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.4 eV
   ../0.5/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.5 eV
   ../0.6/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.6 eV
   ../0.7/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.7 eV
   ../0.8/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.8 eV
   ../0.9/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 0.9 eV
   ../1.0/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 1.0 eV
   ../1.1/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 1.1 eV
   ../1.2/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 1.2 eV
   ../1.3/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TSHS 1.3 eV
%endblock
%block TBT.Contours
  IV
%endblock
%block TBT.Contour.IV
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock


# This is the remaining default SIESTA options
PAO.BasisSize         SZP

XC.functional     GGA
XC.authors        PBE
MeshCutoff        300.000000 Ry
FilterCutoff      150.000000 Ry

ElectronicTemperature   300 K

MinSCFIterations       3
SCF.DM.Tolerance       0.0001
# Mixing parameters:
SCF.Mixer.Weight       0.010
SCF.Mixer.History      12
SCF.Mix.First          true
DM.UseSaveDM           true

MD.NumCGSteps 0

SaveElectrostaticPotential T
SaveHS                          T
%include ../DEVICE.fdf



Before reading the following answer,please read this question first Where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra?

I extracted the transmission functions at different bias voltage, as shown in the following picture.

Here, I extracted the transmission functions using the following code and I assumed that 0 eV is the fermi energy in the transmission spectra.
tbt = sisl.get_sile('./TBT_0.1/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TBT.nc')
plt.plot(tbt.E, tbt.transmission(), label='k-averaged');
plt.plot(tbt.E, tbt.transmission(kavg=tbt.kindex([0, 0, 0])), label=r'$\Gamma$'); 
plt.xlabel('Energy [eV]'); plt.ylabel('Transmission'); plt.ylim([0, None]); plt.legend();

Results and conclusion:
At 0.1 bias voltage, the gap (0.1247 eV) around fermi energy is comparable with bias voltage, and the fermi energy is closer to valence band, so the bias windows Vb = μL- μR=0.1V includes some finite transmission function around valence band,  this is why there is current flowing at 0.1 V.
From 0.1V to 0.8V, current saturation appeared, this is because the gap increased as the bias voltage increased, and the growth magnitude of the two are almost the same. Therefore, similar magnitude of finite transmission function is included into the bias windows from 0.1 V to 0.8V and current keeps almost the same.
From 0.9V to 1.2V, there are some finite transmission function appearing and increasing near the fermi level. Therefore, more and more transmission function are included in the bias windows and the current is increasing.
